# Cannot find a differ supporting object 'undefined'. Detecting the change of a number inside DoCheck

Tags: angular

I have three variable, 2 object and a number to which I detect change inside an ngDoCheck Lifecycle.

```
export class MyComponent implements DoCheck{

  differ: any;
  @Input() age: number;
  @Input() person: Person;
  @Input() company: Company;

  constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers ) {
      this.differ = {};
      this.differ['age'] = differs.find(this.age).create(null);
      this.differ['person'] = differs.find(this.person).create(null);
      this.differ['company'] = differs.find(this.company).create(null);
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
      var ageChanges = this.differ['age'].diff(this.age);
      var personChanges = this.differ['person'].diff(this.person);
      var companyChanges = this.differ['company'].diff(this.company);

      if(ageChanges || personChanges || companyChanges){
         this.doSomething(); 
      }

      doSOmething(){
      }
   }
```

There's is no promblem in detecting the changes on inputs person and company. I'm getting an error in detecting the change in age. "Cannot find a differ supporting object 'undefined'

Comment: There is not differ for number for `age` you can just compare `var ageChanges = this.age !== this.previousAge;`

Comment: how to get the previous value of age?